# Google Play Music API and unsupported countries

Tags: c#, google-music

I certainly discovered unofficial Google Music API, written in C# (the latest [is located here](https://github.com/jamesmoore/GoogleMusicAPI2.NET)). However, I have no clue how to test it, cause I live in Ukraine, and Google Play Music is unavailable here. Different proxy services are inefficient. 
So, what are the ways to test it?